# Is it a good practise to use underscore to ignore a value that is being passed to a function, which we don't need?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on Django rest framework which specifies a set format for function prototype for `detail_route` in ModelViewSet. Some background: - 
The function takes in `request object` and `lookup_field` which can be the primary key for a particular table.

```
@detail_route(methods=["get"], url_path="get-some-data")
    def get_some_data(self, request, id=None):
        return Response(get_some_data(id))
```

Now as you can see, I do not need request object here, So should I keep it like this? or change it to

```
@detail_route(methods=["get"], url_path="get-some-data")
    def get_some_data(self, _, id=None):
        return Response(get_some_data(id))
```

Here I changed `request` to `_` to indicate that I do not need this value.

which approach should be followed? Should I let it remain as a request, or change it to an underscore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the method arguments I would always use the proper variable name so that in future whether I work on it or my peers if I provide this code to someone else they don't have to struggle to understand what it is.

For now you might think to ignore it but since it is a method argument it would be better to have a name it stands for.

---

Or, let's say you are adding a docstring where you are including and defining which parameter is what. You would yourself appreciate it if some one had:

```
@param request: HTTP request object
```

instead of:

```
@param _: HTTP request object
```

Answer (score 1):

If you leave the parameter exist, then give it a meaningful name always do good, even you do not use it.

In addition, _ has special use in python, check it in the following url.

[What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave it with a descriptive name.  Changing it to underscore or any other non-descriptive name is not beneficial.